# How can I view a ChromeOS App crash log / report?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have a ChromeOS App that runs well on my PC (windows 10) but it crashes when it runs on a Chromebit.

How can I see the app crash log on Chrome OS?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

look in `chrome://crashes` to see if there's anything useful in there.  if not, the app crashing isn't generating any logs to disk for you to browse.

sometimes you can get info via the debug console -- go to `chrome://extensions`, check the developer mode box, and find the app you care about.  see if it has a background page which you can inspect -- click the link and it should pop up a console.  then try launching the app.